# At the age of 27 is it worth shifting PhD. from strings to computer science?

Tags: graduate-school, job-search, computer-science, physics, age

Will the effort required to learn a completely new subject from scratch be outweighed by the better job prospects when one is looking for faculty positions?

Comment: Only you can answer that, but the more important consideration is: if you dislike doing string theory enough to consider switching, will you have any job prospects if you don't?

Comment: Can't answer the question at hand, but switching to computer science because you think it will be easier to score a faculty position is ... optimistic.

Comment: While I think there is an important question related to what you are asking, as it stands your question does not seem like a good fit since it is not possible to give meaningful answers to questions that focus on perceived effort and benefits.

Comment: @xLeitix But isn't it true that the faculty position jobs are still much easier to get in theoretical CS than in string theory? [...in an ideal world I would have wanted to do string theory - since thats what I really love doing...]

Comment: I don't know what the situation in theoretical physics is, but in Europe you will in average compete with 100 or  so other people for each of the (few) suitable faculty positions that become available per year, so there's an really good chance that you are going to switch fields only to also not find a faculty job in CS.

Comment: To clarify, I truly believe that there are more positions for CS than for string theory, but there are also **much more** computer scientists than theoretical physicists on the market. And, likely, you will not exactly have a starting advantage when you are the one that is actually passionate about another field.

Comment: _isn't it true that the faculty position jobs are still much easier to get in theoretical CS than in string theory?_ — **NO.**

Comment: The terms easy and easier should never be used in reference to an academic job search. Getting a job in any field is difficult and it is more difficult in some fields.

Comment: Re: Strongbad.  In some fields it is very easy:  (paywalled) http://chronicle.com/article/Believe-It-or-Not-in-Some/147207/

Comment: @user6818 How many years are you studying this major? How much is it left to graduate PhD?

Comment: @Parsa I am in my 3rd year of PhD - and my physics PhD is going no where since I don't have access to the topics which interest me.

Comment: @user6818 Did not you have to define a topic and proposal in the second year of your PhD? Because I have know most of the PhD students are almost required to finish their courses in the first year, defend their proposal in the second year, work on their research topic in the third year and do their visits, work on their papers and write their dissertation in the fourth year.

Answer (score 1):

Will your degree actually say 'String Theory' rather than 'Physics'? If so, this is unfortunately narrow, and given the uncertain future of string theory as a field I'd rectify it as soon as possible. How close are you to finishing? I wouldn't dump a Physics doctorate a year from completion to start over in CS. If I wanted to change fields, I'd just do a master's afterwards.